# Removing the flywheel of a portable generator

Tags: flywheel, generator

This is a portable generator:

[image]

I want to disassemble the flywheel by first removing that nut. I tried the method which involves trapping the piston at its top dead center and turning the nut clockwise. I couldn't do it. Maybe I didn't apply the force as sudden as the job required. Do you suggest any special tools? Would an electric or air wrench do the job?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If you are going to put it back together, the coil for the magneto needs to be in the correct position ( something like 0.010" from the flywheel.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wrote correctly, most nuts are removed *counter*-clockwise (or anti-clockwise if you prefer). You turn it clockwise to tighten it.

Be careful with how you've "trapped" your piston as it is fairly fragile. Don't use the flywheel itself as you'll break off the fan veins. If you break anything on it, it will require a new one because it would then be out of balance. If you can hold the crank from the other side of the engine, it would probably be a good way to go.

Comment: Agree that does look like it should come off in a counter-clockwise direction.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, it is not reverse threaded. I have unscrewed it